# Sort one list, display the order in another

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery-Ui's sortable, and am stuck. I am able to sort the contents of one list, but am lost at how to affect another lists order based on the newly sorted previous lists.

Basically, what I am trying to do is sort #smalllist, and then when I complete the sort, automatically sort #biglist based on the order of #smalllist and have it display within the DOM immediately. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sorting Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#smalllist").sortable();
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">

        li { 
            list-style-type: none;
            float: left;
        }
        #biglist img{
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        #bigpics{
            position: absolute;
            top: 400px;
        }
        #smalllist{
            cursor: move; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="smallicons">
        <ul id="smalllist">
             <li id='s_1'><img src="img/article01_small.jpg" /></li>
             <li id='s_2'><img src="img/article02_small.jpg" /></li>
             <li id='s_3'><img src="img/article03_small.jpg" /></li>
             <li id='s_4'><img src="img/article04_small.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="bigpics">
        <ul id="biglist">
             <li id='b_1'><img src="img/article01.jpg" /></li>
             <li id='b_2'><img src="img/article02.jpg" /></li>
             <li id='b_3'><img src="img/article03.jpg" /></li>
             <li id='b_4'><img src="img/article04.jpg" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#smalllist").sortable({
        update: function( event, ui ) {
            $("li","#smalllist").each(function() {
                console.log(this)
                $('#' + this.id.replace('s_','b_')).appendTo('#biglist');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This does move the items in #biglist, but it moves them at the same time, and sometimes #biglist does not reflect the order of #smalllist. I want the lists to sort asynchronously.

Comment: @RyanDuffing - Not sure I get what you mean by asynchronously? Maybe try the update event instead, that fires after the sort, edited the answer ?

Comment: your new solution works. Thanks so much. Asynchronously meant that I wanted #biglist to sort immediately after #smalllist completed. At least that's what I think the word means, one after another?

Comment: Yeah, the update event should do that, both that and the stop event will fire after the sort, but update will only fire if something changes, while stop will always fire, so using the update event is probably the best option.